# how to use modal pop up in angularjs-ui bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using angularjs. What i want to do is when user click button , angularjs will checking item id in database. If item id exist in database, #modal will be showed instead of alert like this question. Is it possible to do this with angularjs? If possible how..

HTML

```
    <div id="container" ng-app='two_way' ng-controller="aa" >
<div align="center">
 <h1 align="center">  Nutrition Scheduling List </h1>
        <button ng-click="loadsched()" >LOAD SCHEDULE</button>
</div>
<span ng-hide="load==null">
<table border='1' bgcolor="CCFFFF" align="center">
<tr ><td><b>Item Name</b></td><td><b>Scheduled Time</b></td><td><b>Run Time</b></td><td><b>Create Time</b></td><td><b>Status</b></td><td><b>Response</b></td></tr>
 <tr ng-repeat="data in load | orderBy: 'searchitem'">
    <td>
         {{data.searchitem}}
        </td>
    <td>
         {{data.Scheduledtime}}
        </td>
    <td>
         {{data.runt}}
        </td>
    <td>
         {{data.CurrentTime}}
        </td>
    <td>
         {{data.STATUS}}
        </td>
    <td>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="RESPONSE" onclick="window.open('http://localhost:3000/search/{{data._id}}','popUpWindow','height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');">
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
</span>
    <script src="more.js"></script>
    </div>
```

Controller more.js

```
var app=angular.module('two_way', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('aa',function($scope,$http){

$scope.loadsched=function(){

  $http.post("http://localhost:3000/a").success(function(data){    
//console.log(data);

    $scope.load=angular.fromJson(data);



  }).error(function(){alert("Error");});
}


});
```

Comment: Did you check official docs for modal? http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: @arogachev i have cheked but not sure how to apply in given code ...

Comment: You didn't show your efforts in this , i cannot find anything related to modal here except dependency 'ui.bootstrap'.

Comment: @squiroid you are right but i want to apply 'ui.bootstrap' in my code how can i??

Answer (score 0):

Very simple :-

1) Apply $modal to your main controller.

2) Use `$modal.open()` to open modal  anywhere and it will return a promise.

```
 $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size
);
```

Here template is file or Id of your modal template.
size:sm,lg 
Controller it is the controller of your modal.
For example:-

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

$modalInstance service is used to close and return the promise from modal.

`$modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);` close the modal and return data to controller.

`$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');` it is simply dismiss the controller.

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
```

Here `modalInstance.result` is used to get data from modal controller to your main controller.

Official [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JI9W1WNbhKrzSztqvN7x?p=preview)